# CRM 9 - Bind HTML Table/Grid dynamically based on records from JS

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am working on a HTML Page inside Dynamics CRM 9.0. I have written a Webresource JavaScript which I have called through the HTML page.
There is a function in my JavaScript that fetches data from the CRM entity like below,

```
var Query = "$select=ParameterValue,transactioncode,ParameterName&$filter= PhonceCallId/Id eq(guid'" + phoneid + "')";
 XrmSvcToolkit.retrieveMultiple({
    entityName: entity ,  
    odataQuery: Query,
    async: false,
    successCallback: successCallback,
    errorCallback: errorCallback
});
```

Now, against the PhoneCallId, I am retrieving records and please note that the records are dynamic in nature which means the number of rows fetched against each hit is not fixed (I may get 3 rows first time, 5 rows the next time and so on).

I want to dynamically bind these records into my HTML page like a gridview which will have header columns and then the records will be bind at runtime on that gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you could achieve This.
For Example here is one of my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/538/) using KnockoutJS which does populate data. In this fiddle Data is static for explanation and this can be dynamically populated from CRM and you could shown how many Rows once wish to show per page.
Below code is just Ref to Fiddle

Basically below code is what you need for getting data from CRM into your local Array

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=accountnumber,emailaddress1,name&$filter=accountid ne null", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
var tempArray = new array();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var accountnumber = results.value[i]["accountnumber"];
                var emailaddress1 = results.value[i]["emailaddress1"];
                var name = results.value[i]["name"];
                tempArray.push(results.value[i]["accountnumber"],results.value[i]["emailaddress1"],results.value[i]["name"]);

            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Normal HTML Table adding data. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insert_deleterow) for Reference

Comment: Dear  @AnkUser. Thanks for your reply, But i am getting data inside ResponseData variable and I do not want pagination. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Here is one more Basic HTML Example of creating Dynamics Table https://jsfiddle.net/JSFiddleChamp/ycfdL3oe/2/

In Array you could add your data coming from RetreiveMultiple and then simply loop through array and display Data. This will get you rolling.
If this help you move ahead, please mark it as solved.

Comment: When I am trying to access my ResponseData like this ResponseData[0][0]. It is giving me an error undefined whereas when I query like this ResponseData[0]["ParameterValue"] it gives me ParameterValue at 0th index

Comment: You are confusing value coming from Crm to an JavaScript array object. What you need to do is create an Array variable, one by one insert your value from Response data into Array. Then you have array object (local)with all the data from Crm and thenon show value from array into table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please show me an example of how can i do that?

Comment: Alright I have updated my Fiddle, you could check here https://jsfiddle.net/JSFiddleChamp/ycfdL3oe/7/

I have updated my answer as well.Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Dear thank you so much for your help. I have achieved the result. But can you also help me in understanding the concept of achieving the same result through KnockOut? As I have not worked with that way before would be extremely grateful. Also I am up voting the answer and accepting this answer

Comment: Well Knockout is one of many Frameworks for Js. I would suggest you use veujs Framework. But you will have to learn the Framework yourself

Comment: No I mean the fiddle example that you showed me earlier. I want to use the same but i do not have static data I have data inside ResponseData and I do not want to use pagination.